# Should dealer continue dealing after one of the players hits royal flush in heads-up showdown?

Tags: texas-hold-em, dealing, dealer

I've just watched [this hand](https://youtu.be/ylX8hYJDw30?t=131). In the hand one of the players hits a royal flush on the turn in a heads-up showdown hand. The dealer does not proceed to the river because, at this point, it's obvious who has won.

Is this always the case? In other words: should the dealer continue dealing when it's obvious who's won before the river? Is there any official ruling/recommendations on this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the entire board is dealt in all cases, but I don't see why that earlier stop may cause any problem.

There are no standardized inernational rules for poker, so I guess the house gets to choose

Comment: `I don't see why that earlier stop may cause any problem` - I'm not claiming it does. It's just that it's the first time I've seen a hand without the river that's all.

Comment: @jannis I'm not claiming you claimed it did :)

Comment: `I'm not claiming you claimed it did` We can do this all day long :)

Comment: I'm not claiming you claimed I claimed you did actually claim it. Time to stop it. Next reply I'll give up :)

Answer (score 2):

In the video, the dealer does in fact, deal 5 cards. It has no effect on the game's outcome, but a pro dealer will pitch all the cards in a showdown. The main reason is to not confuse the eye in the sky, or a recreational player.

However, this dealer is making multiple mistakes. It's a case of a little knowledge being dangerous. She is clearly experienced, but not THAT experienced.

Of course, I'm only a dealer trainer in Las Vegas. It's a lost art form, there are almost no good dealers anymore.

Slide pitch. I guess this is OK in Europe? It's a cheating move, but this dealer isn't cheating. You should beware a slide pitch, because it is a way for journeyman cheats to deal 2nds.

Reverse Claw Grip. She is probably doing this because her wrists hurt. Very sloppy.

She drops the stub continuously.

I hate this European one at a time flop.

Poker should be banned in Europe until they get some sense. ;)

Comment: I would say she is dealing to procedures there. Which I agree are crap, especially the reverse claw and slide pitch.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the dealer does have to deal all 5 cards.

Consider this:

Player A: 10dJd
Player B: AcAs

Flop: QdKd2s
Turn: Ad (Royal Flush Made)
River: Ad

So, there are 2 Ace of diamonds in the deck and the hand is not valid. If they'd not dealt the river, Player B would have been cheated out of their money.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes. The dealer should deal all five cards and that's what will happen in a serious event.

But anyway, what's the difference? Who cares?

Answer (score 0):

In some countries is a must by law.

But actually for players is also interesting. Some situations completing at river might have jackpots, like straight flush vs quads or quads vs quads.